# Unable to import Fabric in unity 5.6

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

After updating to unity 5.6, i'm unable to load Fabric. When performing the API update, the API updater fails. After investigation, the issues went away after removing Crashlytics / Fabric.

After installing the unity package from the fabric site, the API updater fails with this cryptic message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x000a3] in <776c86d7978548379a28dce0f5e4ccbb>:0
```

If I cancel the api updater, I get the following deprecation warnings from unity:

```
Assets/Fabric/Editor/GUI/Controller/PluginController.cs(58,45): error CS0619: `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.bundleIdentifier' is obsolete: `Use PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier instead (UnityUpgradable) -> UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier'

Assets/Fabric/Editor/Postbuild/FabricBuildEventAndroid.cs(36,34): error CS0619: `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.bundleIdentifier' is obsolete: `Use PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier instead (UnityUpgradable) -> UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier'

Assets/Fabric/Editor/Prebuild/AndroidBuildPropertiesManager.cs(30,38): error CS0619: `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.bundleIdentifier' is obsolete: `Use PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier instead (UnityUpgradable) -> UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.applicationIdentifier'
```

Even if I sort these deprecations out manually, I'm still unable to run fabric. It seems also i'm not the only experiencing this issue, [see this link from twittercommunity](https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-import-problem-in-unity-5-6-0f1/84109/13)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed the Fabric settings `asset` file from the "Editor Default Resources" folder and after fixing the deprecation issues (manually) i was able to finally launch fabric and download the crashlytics kit.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! We (Fabric) are looking into this. Really appreciate you publicizing your workaround.